# Carrusel de Bootstrap retrocede a la imagen anterior solo

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, carrusel

Cuando le doy a cualquiera de los controladores pasa a la siguiente y a su vez, retrocede a la primera imagen. He comprobado que no son los enlaces de Bootstrap y el HTML es un copia y pega del mismo, lo que falla es en el CSS la clase *producto*, el `display:inline-flex`, pero no sé cómo hacerlo sin él, porque necesito hacer esa misma disposición.

He probado a hacer el mismo sin CSS y funciona perfectamente, pero necesito que esté dispuesto de esa forma.

**HTML y CSS**

```css
/* Carousel */
/* Change the size of the carousel */
.carousel-item.producto {
    min-height: 900px;
}
.producto {
    /* Color de fondo */
    background-color: #f4feff;
    /* Posicionamiento de las imágenes*/
    display: inline-flex !important;
    justify-content: center !important;
    align-items: center !important;
    padding: 30px;
    margin-top: -150px;
    position: absolute;
}
/*  Images of the carrousel */
.producto > img {
    /* Le quitamos el espacio entre ellas */
    margin: 0 !important;
    background-size: contain;
}
/* Card positions */
.card-body {
    position: absolute;
    align-self: flex-end;
    clear: both;
}
.c1 {
    margin-left: -500px; 
}
.c1 > a{
    margin-left: 70px;
}
.c2 > a{
    margin-left: 15px;
}
.c2 {
    margin-left: 495px;
}
.c1,.c2 {
    bottom: 70px !important;
}
/* Height of carousel controls*/
.carousel-control-prev, .carousel-control-next {
    height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="./prueba.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

    <div id="carouselExample" class="carousel carousel-dark slide">
        <div class="carousel-inner">

            <div class="carousel-item active producto">
                <img class="d-block mx-auto img-fluid col-md-4 col-6" src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/la.jpg"
                    height="400" width="530">
                <div class="card-body c1">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Nezuko Kamado kimetsu No Yaiba</h4>
                    <p class="card-text">35.99 €</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary text-center">Add to basket</a>
                </div>
                <img class="d-block mx-auto img-fluid col-md-4 col-6" src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/ny.jpg"
                    height="400" width="530">
                <div class="card-body c2">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Izuku Midoriya Boku no Hero Academia</h4>
                    <p class="card-text">29.00 €</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary text-center">Add to basket</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Siguiente transición -->
            <div class="carousel-item producto">
                <img class="d-block col-md-4 col-6" src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/chicago.jpg" height="400"
                    width="400">
                <div class="card-body c1">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Póster de la película Your Name</h4>
                    <p class="card-text">5.00 €</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary text-center">Add to basket</a>
                </div>

                <img class="d-block col-md-4 col-6" src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/chicago.jpg" height="400"
                    width="400">
                <div class="card-body c2">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Póster Made in Abyss</h4>
                    <p class="card-text">10.00 €</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary text-center">Add to basket</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Controls -->
        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExample" data-bs-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExample" data-bs-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
    </div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es que en realidad no está retrocediendo al primer *slide*: de hecho, *primero se está mostrando el segundo *slide**. Esto puede notarse de dos maneras: a través del HTML, por el `div` con clase *active* (que no corresponde al primer *slide* mostrado al ejecutar el código), y porque la *no-transición* se da con números pares, ej.: la primera vez que se clica el botón de navegación pareciera ser que no se mueve (pero en realidad sí se está mostrando el slide que corresponde), y la segunda vez que se clica sí se da el "efecto rebote" descrito en la pregunta.

Hay muchos errores en el código... Es por eso que hay que entender cómo funcionan los componentes de Bootstrap.

---

Resumen de los cambios hechos: **toca reescribir código**.

- Las *col* no funcionan sin *row*... (Al traducir tiene más sentido: *las columnas no funcionan si no están ubicadas en un fila*.) Es más sencillo notarlo en tamaños de pantalla relacionados a móviles, por el *desorden*. En este caso, se movieron las clase *col-6* y *col-md-4* del `img` y se agregó un div de clase *row*, que contiene a su vez un div con la clase mencionada. Para que la fila quede centrada, se agregó la clase *justify-content-center*.
- Los *card-body* deben ubicarse dentro de una *card*. En el código presentado, "están flotando". Probablemente las imágenes son también parte de la *card* (salvo se indique lo contrario). De todos modos, tanto los `div` con la clase *card-body* como las imágenes inmediatamente superiores, fueron movidas a unos `div` de clase *card*.
- A las `img` se les agregó la clase *card-img-top*, para que ellas abarquen todo el ancho del *card* que las contiene, y *rounded-0*, para que la imagen no aparezca con las esquinas redondeadas.
- A tales *card* también se les agregó la clase *producto*. En lugar de

```
.producto > img {
    margin: 0 !important;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

ahora aparece

```
.producto > img {
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

El espaciado entre una *card* y otra se manejará de otra manera, es por eso que se removió la propiedad `margin`. En lugar de repetir la imagen para cubrir el espacio sobrante, se removió la propiedad `background-size: contain`. En su lugar, se agregó la propiedad `object-fit: cover`, para que cuando el tamaño de la *card* sea menor a la imagen, esta última "conserve su centro" en lugar de "aplastarse".

- El `margin` previamente removido fue reemplazado: se agregó al `div` con la clase *col-6* la clase *pe-0* (*padding end*) para el ítem de la izquierda, y la clase *ps-0* (*padding start*) para el ítem de la derecha.
- Para eliminar el color blanco de *card*, se agregó un background transparente, de la siguiente manera:

```
.card.producto{
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

- Para eliminar el borde de cada *card*, se les agregó la clase *border-0*.
- El padding de 30px fue movido a la clase *row*.
- El margin-top se modificó de -150px a un padding-top de 120px (*es arbitrario*.)

```css
.producto>img {
  object-fit: cover;
}

.carousel-item {
  background-color: #f4feff;
}

.card.producto {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.carousel-item.producto {
  min-height: 900px;
}

.row {
  padding: 30px;
  padding-top: 120px;
}

.c1>a {
  margin-left: 70px;
}

.c2>a {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.c1,
.c2 {
  bottom: 70px !important;
}


/* Height of carousel controls*/

.carousel-control-prev,
.carousel-control-next {
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="./prueba.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="carouselExample" class="carousel carousel-dark slide">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-6 col-md-4 pe-0">
            <div class="card producto border-0">
              <img class="card-img-top rounded-0" src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/la.jpg" alt="" height="400" width="530">
              <div class="card-body c1">
                <h4 class="card-title">Nezuko Kamado kimetsu No Yaiba</h4>
                <p class="card-text">35.99 €</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary text-center">Add to basket</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6 col-md-4 ps-0">
            <div class="card producto border-0">
              <img class="card-img-top rounded-0" src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/ny.jpg" alt="" height="400" width="530">
              <div class="card-body c2">
                <h4 class="card-title">Izuku Midoriya Boku no Hero Academia</h4>
                <p class="card-text">29.00 €</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary text-center">Add to basket</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Siguiente transición -->
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-6 col-md-4 pe-0">
            <div class="card producto border-0">
              <img class="card-img-top rounded-0" src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/chicago.jpg" alt="" height="400" width="400">
              <div class="card-body c1">
                <h4 class="card-title">Póster de la película Your Name</h4>
                <p class="card-text">5.00 €</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary text-center">Add to basket</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6 col-md-4 ps-0">
            <div class="card producto border-0">
              <img class="card-img-top rounded-0" src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/chicago.jpg" alt="" height="400" width="400">
              <div class="card-body c2">
                <h4 class="card-title">Póster Made in Abyss</h4>
                <p class="card-text">10.00 €</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary text-center">Add to basket</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExample" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExample" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      </button>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Como podrá notarse, la sección de CSS quedó mucho más corta, delegándose la mayor parte de las modificaciones a las clases que provee el propio Bootstrap.
Para comprender cómo funciona cada clase agregada, hay que visitar y leer [la documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/).